# print currency symbol near a database fetch number

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

If I have a **price** field on mysql table, with a decimal number, and I fetch the entire row to view it in a table (via Codeigniter 3 with the:

```
 <?php echo $this->table->generate($query); ?>
```

method ).

How can I add the € symbol near the decimal number?

Comment: What you are currently doing is creating or "generating" a table. What you need to show is how you are coming up with your `$query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print it easily,using `'&euro;'`,

```
 <?php echo '&euro;';echo $this->table->generate($query); ?>
```